# Outputted text as a shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

OK, I have a working line of code that acts nearly as I want it to, but instead of creating a shortcode in WordPress, it just spits out the text. I need the outputted text to be a shortcode. I've tried everything I know of, but to no avail.

Can someone alter this code so that it outputs the text (beginning with [imdb]http://... as a shortcode?

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
if( get_post_meta($postid, 'imdb', true)) { ?>
<h3>IMDb Information</h3>
[imdb]http://www.imdb.com/title/<?php echo get_post_meta($postid, 'imdb', true);
?>/[/imdb]
<?php } 
       elseif( get_post_meta($postid, 'ecpt_imdb', true)) { 
?>
<h3>IMDb Information</h3>
[imdb]http://www.imdb.com/title/<?php echo get_post_meta($postid, 'ecpt_imdb',    true);
?>/[/imdb]
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: what do you mean for short code ? a link? an ancor?

Comment: Basically this code works, but it spits out this:
[imdb]http://www.imdb.com/title/imdb_of_movie/[/imdb]

I want to have that line of text above be a shortcode instead of plain text. In essence, I can't get it to work with the do_shortcode function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I am not getting your code, and in that case sorry. But if the idea is that it should print out the result of the [imdb] shortcode, which I imagine would create some kind of information taken from IMDB, probably what you want is something close to:

```
<h3>IMDb Information</h3>
<?= do_shortcode("[imdb]http://www.imdb.com/title/" . get_post_meta($postid, 'imdb', true) . "[/imdb]") ?>
```